# Is the image of a closed subset in a Banach space under a linear and continuous projection closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

I was wondering if the following conjecture is true:
let $X$ be a Banach space, let $P: X\to X$ be a continuous linear projection, and let $C$ be a closed subspace (unrelated to $P$) of $X$.
Then the image $P[C]$ is closed.
By saying that $C$ is not related to $P$, I mean that we do not suppose that $C$ is contained in the image of $P$, that is, we do not know any relationship between $C$ and $P$.
I have thought that the continuity of $P$ implies the continuity of $I-P$. But it turns out that $Ker (I-P)$ doesn't depend on $C$. So I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: No, this already fails in Hilbert space. You should ask this on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Professor, thank you very much for your prompt response. You are very kind.